# How to configure the connection manager in SSIS to connect to a MySQL database on a remote server?

Tags: mysql, ssis, ssis-connection-manager

I am trying to configure the connection manager in SSIS using .Net Providers\MySQL Data Provider to connect to a MySQL database on a remote server. I am basically following this tutorial

https://smallbusiness.chron.com/connect-mysql-ssis-60851.html

I typed the Database and server name and the UserId who is a database user as well as the corresponding password. But when I test connect, it gives the following error
[image]
I am certain that the input information is correct. What could be the possible reason that I am getting this error?

By the way, the server login user and the database user are not the same. (But do we even need the server login user at all?)

Comment: I believe your issue is that root-level remote access is not enabled. Check out the first answer to this question to see if it solves your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779104/how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql

Comment: Thanks, that answer solved the problem. I needed to create a user for my specific 'desired_ip' and grant the permission